# javascript timer or intervals created in loop using closure

Tags: javascript, loops, timer, closures, setinterval

I'm using jQuery to setup a timer or interval loop on a few elements to check them every couple seconds.  I've tried setting a timer and checking if I should restart it, or setting and interval and checking if I should stop it.

Although simplified, this is basically what I need:

```
var mytimers = new Array();
$('div.items').each(function() {
    myID = $(this).attr('id');
    mytimers[myID] = setInterval( function() { myFunction(myID) } , 3000)
});
function myFunction(param) {
    alert(param);
    if (something()) {
        clearInterval(mytimers[param]);
    }
}
```

The ID's for class items are id_1, id_2, id_3. But I simply get 3 alerts all giving id_3.  In my code I started off trying to pass 'this', but kept simplifying it to figure out the issue.

How can I get it to copy the variable to a new address each time?  I know I need to use closures.  It seems to be referencing the other var no mater what.

I tried simplifying it to a loop with timers like so:

```
function tester(item) {
    return function() {
        alert(item);
    };
}
for(x=1;x<=3;x++) {
    setTimeout( '(function() { tester(x) })(x)' , 3000);
}
```

But I think I'm just making my problem worse and that doesn't seem to do anything.

I've searched for previous questions, but most are filled with tons of extra code rather than cutting it down the the specific issue and are solved in some other manner.
I'd like to understand how this works better by getting this example working.  I did manage, while writing this, to figure out I can set off  the timer with a helping function.

```
function tester(item)
    alert(item);
function myTimer(item)
    setInterval( function() { tester(item); }, 3000);
for(x=1;x<=3;x++)
    myTimer(item);
```

How can this be done without that? Is there some better way?

Comment: You really should be declaring *all* your local variables with `var`, including loop indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in a closure when you use each, you just have forgotten var to make your variable private in the function scope

```
var mytimers = new Array();
$('div.items').each(function() {
    **var** myID = $(this).attr('id'); 
    mytimers[myID] = setInterval( function() { myFunction(myID) } , 3000)
});
function myFunction(param) {
    alert(param);
    if (something()) {
        clearInterval(mytimers[param]);
    }
}
```

Comment: *smacks forehead* I actually tried var in all sorts of places, except that one, ha.

Answer (score 4):

Have variable 'myID' local to the anonymous function,

```
var myID = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to run `myFunction` on each of the matched elements every three seconds?

Try this:

```
$('div.items').each( myFunction(this) );

var myFunction = function(elem) {
    return function() {
        if ( something(elem) ) {
            //return or do something with elem
        } else {
            window.setTimeout( myFunction(elem), 3000 );
        }
    }
};
```

If the condition in `something()` is met you're done, if not the function schedules itself to run again in 3 seconds with the same element as before. You can call this as many times as you want on different elements, each call has its own `elem`.

I prefer to pass objects like elem around and delay working with their internals until the last possible moment. Let `something()` worry about the id or whatever.

None of the other gymnastics with the associative array (instead of `new Array()` you could just use `{}`), or `clearInterval`, or ID's are necessary.

To actually address your solution, as Marimuthu said, you left `var` off the declaration of `myID`, which means its global and it gets overwritten each iteration. The result is that when `setInterval` invokes `myFunction` instead of getting a unique local `myID` via closure, you get the global one that has already been overwritten umpty times.