# get global variable , from function `change`

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
function getSelectData(id) {
var value='';

    // set value to be the current selected value
value = jQuery(id+" option:selected").val();

// change value whenever the box changes
jQuery(id).change(function () {
    value = jQuery(id+" option:selected").val();
});

console.log(value);
return value;
```

}

Thanks to @Hogan , he help me but still i can not get wanted result , how i can get variable `value` , outside function `change` , here is this example http://jsfiddle.net/ZvuMh/ , and every time when i'm  changing select box , value is `a` . Thank You  for your spending time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery , access variable from function ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100524/jquery-access-variable-from-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unless you move it to be a global variable.  As it is, the line "console.log(value)" will only print the value before the function change() is called.  (change() gets called when something changes....but that is long after getSelectData() has returned).

Comment: Just to clarify, as you have it "value" is not a global.  If it is declared above "function getSelectData(id) {", it would be, and you could access it from anywhere.  Probably bad design, but that is the most direct way of making it accessible from elsewhere.  Your "console.log(value)" line, however, will only show it's value BEFORE change() is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here, use this as a template to solve your problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZvuMh/3/